# Are there correct encodings for the backslash and tilde characters in Shift_JIS?

Tags: character-encoding, iconv, shift-jis

Or do these two characters simply not exist in Shift_JIS?

The first 128 characters in the Shift_JIS character encoding scheme match ASCII except for two: 0x5C is a Yen symbol (`¥`) instead of a backslash, and 0x7E is an overline (`‾`) instead of a tilde.

While there's plenty of clear information about how `¥` and `‾` takeover for `\` and `~`, I haven't been able to find any clear statement about whether `\` and `~` simply don't exist in Shift_JIS, or if there are alternate (probably multi-byte) encodings to handle these two displaced ASCII characters.

When I try to encode `\` or `~` using [node-iconv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv), it throws an error.

[iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) encodes both `¥` and `\` as 0x5C, and both `‾` and `~` as 0x7E. When decoding, iconv-lite currently (and unfortunately) decodes 0x5C as `\` and 0x7E as `~`, pending response to a bug report:

- https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/issues/218

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Character set of Shift_JIS is defined in JIS (Japanese Industrial Standard).

Character encoding Shift_JIS uses JIS X 0201 for half-width character set, and JIS X 0208 for full-width character set.

`\` and `~` in the question mean the half-width backslash and tilde in ISO/IEC 8859-1(Latin-1), right? JIS X 0201 (half-width character set) doesn't contain these characters (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201).

So the answer is, both of `\` and `~` don't exist in Shift_JIS.

FYR, JIS X 0208 contains full-width backslash (FULLWIDTH REVERSE SOLIDUS, U+FF3C in Unicode). JIS X 0208 doesn't contain full-width tilde, but Shift_JIS equivalent in Windows (Microsoft Codepage 932) contains full-width tilde (FULLWIDTH TILDE, U+FF5E in Unicode).

Comment: It's very odd that two characters so commonly used in coding would be totally left out! Displaced I can see, but totally missing is surprising. I guess these days UTF-8 and other encodings have pretty much taken over, however, so this is just a legacy issue at this point.

Comment: It's not so odd. All it means is that Shift-JIS is not a suitable encoding for writing program source code. That doesn't make Shift-JIS any less suitable for encoding text documents. There is nothing preventing you from writing a program whose source code is in UTF-8 or ASCII, which processes text documents using Shift-JIS. An analogy is that you can write a C compiler using FORTRAN source code. Or write laws for France in the English language.