# Python and support for EUC-KR

Tags: python, character-encoding, iconv

I am trying to play with string encoding in python 3.10, in particular to demonstrate the [yen/won/backslash](https://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/09/17/469941.html) encoding issue.

So the [following behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819615/are-there-correct-encodings-for-the-backslash-and-tilde-characters-in-shift-jis) (irreversible mapping) makes sense to me:

```
>>> "¥".encode("shift-jis").decode("shift-jis")
'\\'
```

I can also verify with my iconv copy:

```
$ echo -n "¥" | iconv -f utf-8 -t shift-jis | hexdump
0000000 005c
0000001
```

Now I struggle to understand the following behavior:

```
>>> "₩".encode("euc-kr")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'euc_kr' codec can't encode character '\u20a9' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

While:

```
$ echo -n "₩" | hexdump
0000000 82e2 00a9
0000003
$ echo -n "₩" | iconv -f utf-8 -t euc-kr | hexdump
0000000 dca3
0000002
$ echo -n "₩" | iconv -f utf-8 -t euc-kr | iconv -f euc-kr -t utf-8 | hexdump
0000000 bfef 00a6
0000003
```

My naive understanding of KS X 1001 (registered as ISO-IR 149), was that `₩` really is `\`  ([*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KS_X_1001#Encodings)):

> Encoding schemes of KS X 1001 include EUC-KR (in both ASCII and ISO
> 646-KR based variants, the latter of which includes a won currency
> sign (₩) at byte 0x5C rather than a backslash)

What did I misundertood from `KS X 1001` and `₩` ?

1. Why python isn't returning the `\` symbol ?
2. Why iconv is returning code `dca3` (U+FFE6 FULLWIDTH WON SIGN) for `₩` (U+20A9, WON SIGN) ?

For reference:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.12
```

and

```
$ iconv --version
iconv (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) 2.35
```

Comment: Perhaps you have found a bug in the Python codecs. For what it's worth, `"\uffe6".encode("euc_kr")` works, and produces `b'\xa3\xdc'` i.e. your expected output: and `b'\\'.decode("euc_kr")` simply returns a literal backslash.

Comment: OK, here we go : https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/114428 let's see what they have to say about this behavior

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Unicode has *two* Won symbols: [U+20A9 Won Sign](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+20A9) and [U+FFE6 Fullwidth Won Sign](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FFE6).  Python has implemented the fullwidth version but you're testing the other one.  They may have done this precisely to avoid the problem you were testing for.  This works fine:

```
"\uffe6".encode("euc-kr")
b'\xa3\xdc'
```

Comment: Although, this is not unusual for cross-walking between Korean standards and Unicode. For instance Jamo in EUC-KR will map to compatibility Jamo in Unicode rather than to the composable Jamo that are the norm in Unicode if your data is NFD or are using archaic syllables..